# how can i call return array from Swift class to swiftui view file

Tags: swift

**My function in class page;
soru an object and [soru] an array list.**

```
func GetSorular()->[Soru] {
    NetworkManager.instance.fetch(HTTPMethod.get, url: "https://app.kivacrm.com/api/v1/data/osym/sorular" , requestModel: nil, model: SorularResponse.self ) { response in
        switch(response)
        {
            case .success(let model):
                let sorularModel = model as! SorularResponse
                for soru in sorularModel.records {
                    self.sorularArray.append(soru)
                }
            
        case .failure(_):
            print("Failure e girdi!")
        }
    }
    print("results:\(sorularArray)")
    return sorularArray
}
```

return result empty..

the printing and viewpage getting result is unfortunately blank;

```
results:[]
count Sorular :0
```

in View code:

```
var sorular=DerslerController().GetSorular();
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  can't structure your code the way your are trying to.
Your `NetworkManager`'s `fetch()` method is asynchronous. It returns immediately, and the closure you pass to it gets executed at some point later, after your
`GetSorular()` function has already returned without appending anything to your array. Instead, you need to refactor your `GetSorular()` to take a completion handler.

Your code might look like this: (Note that in Swift function names should start with a lower case letter.)

```
//Instead of trying to return the results, take a completion handler
func getSorular(completion: @escaping ([Soru])->() ) {
    var resultsArray = [Soru]()
    NetworkManager.instance.fetch(HTTPMethod.get, url: "https://app.kivacrm.com/api/v1/data/osym/sorular" , requestModel: nil, model: SorularResponse.self ) { response in
        switch(response)
        {
            case .success(let model):
                let sorularModel = model as! SorularResponse
                for soru in sorularModel.records {
                    resultsArray.append(soru)
                }
            print("results:\(resultsArray)")
        case .failure(_):
            print("Failure e girdi!")
        }
        completion(resultsArray)  //Instead of trying to return the results, pass them to the completion handler
    }
}
```

Then you'd call the function like this:

```
getSorular { results in
    self.sorularArray.append(contentsOf: results)
    //Do whatever else you need to do with your sorularArray
}
```

I refactored the code so it builds a local array and returns it rather than appending to a global array. That is much safer.

Comment: Thak u.its running :)